# Sums of infinite series containing terms involving Gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I am looking for relevant literature on sums of series involving the Gamma function. In particular, my interest is in series of the following form.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(c(j+k)) h(j+k)}{\Gamma(n+c(j+k))j!}
\end{equation}

For instance, when $h(j+k) = \Gamma(j+k-\sigma)$ and $c=1$, the sum is equal to the following
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(n-k+\sigma)\frac{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(k-\sigma)}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+\sigma)}
\end{equation}

Can someone suggest relevant literature for similar series, or can someone think of any obvious result for other values of $c$ and the function $h$?